# In Swift how to declare homogeneous array type conforming to Protocol Type

Tags: swift

Consider the code sample below.
Ideally I want the property `ids` to be of of either an array of `String` or `Int` - both of which are `Equatable`.

However, at runtime I want to enforce that the array must be either all `String` types or all `Int` types but not both. How can I enforce this?

```
struct UserListModel {
    // There are other properties here but not relevant to the question
    var ids: [any Equatable]?
}

let greenUsers = UserListModel()
// Compiler allows this
greenUsers.ids = ["1", 2, 3.45]
// However, I want to enforce, something like
// [1, 2, 3]
// or
// ['a', 'b', 'c']

print(greenUsers.ids)
```

Comment: Are `names` and `ids` coupled so that the values at the same index belongs together? If so then I would recommend using a struct instead. (And 3.45 is neither a string or an integer)

Comment: I have edited my question to better explain the query.

Comment: Then I believe you already have a correct answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a generic constraint to your model that will ensure that the array of IDs internally stores values of one type:

```swift
struct Users<ID: Equatable> {
  let ids: [ID]
}

let user1 = Users(ids: [1, 2]) // Works.
let user2 = Users(ids: ["1", "2"]) // Works.
let user3 = Users(ids: ["1", 2]) // Error: Type of expression is ambiguous without more context.
```

If you need to limit the number of types that can be used as IDs, you can additionally define your own type as protocol and make only selected types conform to it:

```swift
protocol ID: Equatable { }

extension Int: ID { }
extension String: ID { }

struct Users<IDType: ID> {
    let ids: [IDType]
}
```

Comment: Thanks! However, I want to keep ids as an optional property so that clients are not forced to specify its type/values at initialization.

Comment: Then make it optional and make any other tweaks to your classes if you wish. My answer doesn't try to figure out the entire design for your app, it only answers your question how to make "the property ids to be of of either an array of String or Int - both of which are Equatable." In the answer, I only include relevant pieces of code to show the idea.

Comment: Right, even with Optional, I'll have to specify the Generic's type at initialization. I am looking for a way to avoid that.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. As you pointed in the question, using an existential type allows mixed elements in the array (different types conforming to the protocol). On the other hand, Swift has a strong type system, and if you need to limit a variable to one, more specific, type, you need to specify it one way or another. But you always can think about a better overall design for you app and make it more generic in other places, too, e.g.: `func makeUsers<IDType: ID>(ids: [IDType]) -> Users<IDType> { Users(ids: ids) }`.

Comment: And another thing, which doesn't relate to the question, but is good to consider. Optional arrays are not good code style in general. The missing of IDs can be denoted by an empty array instead. Having the array optional introduces ambiguity: What does the `nil` array mean, what does the empty array mean, and what's the difference between them?